# Tests and Environments

Tags: postman

i'm newbie here and newbie also using postman.
I'm trying to use environments to store values from responses and use them to the next request. I found some examples on the web and i use them.

I managed to store the first value in a environment but not the 2nd, 3rd, in the same request. I tried many different ways to write the tests but without success

My tests' code is this:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("clientID", jsonData.LoginClientID);
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("COMPANY", jsonData.objs.data[0].LoginCompan
```

Response was this:

```
{
"success": true,
"clientID": "abcd",
"objs": [
    {
        "COMPANY": "1",
        "BRANCH": "1",
        "MODULE": "0",
       }
],
"ver": "5.00.518.11143"
```

}

Running the POST request the value of clientID is stored in enviroment's value but not COMPANY

Any advice ?
Thanks Eddie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `data` part of the code when setting the variable. You're just after the list of items in that `objs` array, not sure where `data` comes into it.

For example, from your code:

`jsonData.objs[0].LoginCompan`

More information about extracting values from a response body can be found here:

https://community.getpostman.com/t/sharing-tips-and-tricks-with-others-in-the-postman-community/5123/5

Comment: Cool, do you want to accept the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers